PyQt6 application auto-closes unexpectedly without leaving any error message
I'm developing a PyQt6 application that deals with real-time acquisition of photon intensity tracking over time and plots it in real-time, before calling a pyo3 function for post-processing on the data. The user has the option to choose whether to automatically perform multiple acquisitions. For example, if they choose to do 5 acquisitions in a row, the software will perform the acquisitions sequentially.
In my MainWindow, I have initialized these variables that handle the queue fetching real-time data:
self.pull_from_queue_timer = QTimer()
self.pull_from_queue_timer.timeout.connect(partial(IntensityTracing.pull_from_queue, self))

In the controller class, I have these functionalities:
start_button_pressed initializes the acquisition process by executing various operations, including GUI manipulation and calling another function that will actually call the external library responsible for starting the acquisition:
@staticmethod
  def start_button_pressed(app):
        IntensityTracingButtonsActions.clear_intensity_grid_widgets(app) 
        app.acquisition_stopped = False
        app.warning_box = None
        app.settings.setValue(SETTINGS_ACQUISITION_STOPPED, False)
        #app.control_inputs[DOWNLOAD_BUTTON].setEnabled(app.write_data and app.acquisition_stopped)
        #self.set_download_button_icon()
        warn_title, warn_msg = MessagesUtilities.invalid_inputs_handler(
            app.bin_width_micros,
            app.time_span,
            app.acquisition_time_millis,
            app.control_inputs[SETTINGS_FREE_RUNNING_MODE],
            app.enabled_channels,
            app.selected_conn_channel,
        )
        if warn_title and warn_msg:
            message_box = BoxMessage.setup(
                warn_title, warn_msg, QMessageBox.Icon.Warning, GUIStyles.set_msg_box_style(), app.test_mode
            )
            app.warning_box = message_box
            return
        app.control_inputs[START_BUTTON].setEnabled(False)
        app.control_inputs[STOP_BUTTON].setEnabled(app.free_running_acquisition_time)   
        app.intensity_charts.clear()
        app.intensity_lines.clear()
        app.last_acquisition_ns = 0
        app.gt_charts.clear()
        app.cps_ch.clear()
        for chart in app.intensity_charts:
            chart.setVisible(False)
        for chart in app.gt_charts:
            chart.setVisible(False)
        for channel, curr_conn in app.intensity_connectors.items():    
            curr_conn.disconnect()
        remove_widget(app.layouts[PLOT_GRIDS_CONTAINER], app.widgets[GT_WIDGET_WRAPPER])      
        gt_widget = create_gt_wait_layout(app)
        insert_widget(app.layouts[PLOT_GRIDS_CONTAINER], gt_widget, 1)    
        app.intensity_connectors.clear()
        app.gt_lines.clear()         
        app.intensity_charts_wrappers.clear()
        QApplication.processEvents()         
        IntensityTracingButtonsActions.intensity_tracing_start(app)
        if not app.widgets[GT_WIDGET_WRAPPER].isVisible():
            IntensityTracingButtonsActions.show_gt_widget(app, True) 
        IntensityTracing.start_photons_tracing(app)


start_photons_tracing function communicates with the external library to start the acquisition and starts the timer connected to the pull_from_queue function:
@staticmethod
    def start_photons_tracing(app):
        try:
            free_running_mode = app.control_inputs[SETTINGS_FREE_RUNNING_MODE].isChecked()
            acquisition_time_millis = (
                None if app.acquisition_time_millis in (0, None) or
                        free_running_mode
                else app.acquisition_time_millis
            )
            print("Selected firmware: " + (str(app.selected_firmware)))
            print("Free running enabled: " + str(free_running_mode))
            print("Acquisition time (ms): " + str(acquisition_time_millis))
            print("Time span (s): " + str(app.time_span))
            print("Max points: " + str(40 * app.time_span))
            print("Bin width (µs): " + str(app.bin_width_micros))
            result = flim_labs.start_intensity_tracing(
                enabled_channels=app.enabled_channels,
                bin_width_micros=app.bin_width_micros, 
                write_bin=False,  
                write_data=True,  
                acquisition_time_millis=acquisition_time_millis, 
                firmware_file=app.selected_firmware,
            )
            if app.acquisitions_count >= app.selected_average:           
                app.widgets[PROGRESS_BAR_WIDGET].clear_acquisition_timer(app)
            if not free_running_mode:
                app.widgets[PROGRESS_BAR_WIDGET].update_acquisitions_count()
                app.widgets[PROGRESS_BAR_WIDGET].setVisible(True)
            file_bin = result.bin_file
            if file_bin != "":
                print("File bin written in: " + str(file_bin))
            app.blank_space.hide()
            app.pull_from_queue_timer.start(1)
            app.last_cps_update_time.start()  
        except Exception as e:
            error_title, error_msg = MessagesUtilities.error_handler(str(e))
            BoxMessage.setup(
                error_title,
                error_msg,
                QMessageBox.Icon.Critical,
                GUIStyles.set_msg_box_style(),
                app.test_mode
            )

pull_from_queue function retrieves real-time data by calling an external library. If the user has set a certain number of acquisitions to be completed sequentially, as soon as one is completed and if the chosen number of acquisitions has not been reached yet, start_button_pressed is called again to restart the process:
    @staticmethod
    def pull_from_queue(app):
        val = flim_labs.pull_from_queue()
        if len(val) > 0:
            for v in val:
                if v == ('end',):  # End of acquisition
                    print("Got end of acquisition, stopping")
                    IntensityTracing.stop_button_pressed(app)
                    if app.acquisitions_count < app.selected_average:
                        IntensityTracingButtonsActions.start_button_pressed(app)    
                    break
                ((time_ns), (intensities)) = v
                IntensityTracing.calculate_cps(app, time_ns[0], intensities)


This is the stop_button_pressed function called:
    def stop_button_pressed(app, app_close = False):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        try:
            flim_labs.request_stop()
        except:
            pass  
        if app.acquisitions_count >= app.selected_average:           
            app.acquisition_count = 0
        else:    
            app.acquisitions_count = app.acquisitions_count + 1  
        app.widgets[PROGRESS_BAR_WIDGET].update_acquisitions_count()            
        app.last_cps_update_time.invalidate() 
        app.control_inputs[START_BUTTON].setEnabled(len(app.enabled_channels) > 0)    
        app.control_inputs[STOP_BUTTON].setEnabled(False)
        if not app_close and app.acquisitions_count == app.selected_average: 
            remove_widget(app.layouts[PLOT_GRIDS_CONTAINER], app.widgets[GT_WIDGET_WRAPPER])
            gt_widget = create_gt_loading_layout(app)
            insert_widget(app.layouts[PLOT_GRIDS_CONTAINER], gt_widget, 1)
        QApplication.processEvents()
        app.pull_from_queue_timer.stop() 
        for channel, curr_conn in app.intensity_connectors.items():     
            curr_conn.pause()          
        if not app_close: 
            if app.acquisitions_count == app.selected_average:
                FCSPostProcessing.get_input(app)  

The issue is this: if I choose to perform multiple acquisitions, this process randomly and unexpectedly freezes, occasionally closing the app without releasing any error. When debugging, the application always freezes inside stop_button_pressed, but the point where it freezes is random.
I tried using another QTimer to separately handle the logic when I have multiple acquisitions, but nothing changed. Where could the problem be? Thanks.

Unfortunately your code contains too many things we know absolutely nothing about, and while we could try to understand it, we would just be guessing (and probably fail). Besides, as already suggested, if you need complex and long CPU-bound computations, you should consider to switch to multi processing. In any case, unless you are able to provide a proper [mre], with your current code there's nothing we can really help you with.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

If flim_labs.pull_from_queue() is blocking, it can freeze the GUI.
Try moving time-consuming operations, like multiprocessing.
